# body onload function is same as refresh button

Tags: javascript, css

i have a main function (startGame) that loads clickable images and when you click it, it disappears (images has its own onClick function that works). It is my body onload function as well.

HTML:

```
<body onload="StartGame()"> //loads all the contents
```

This StartGame function is also a clickable div image among all the other images. When you click this image, it should reload the whole page and the images that disappeared should re-appear again.

CSS:

```
div#startgame{ //clickable css image button 
    background-image: url(../graphics/startgame.png);
    background-size: 165px 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 165px;
    height: 50px;
```

How can i refresh the page everytime i click on it if my function is both my body onload and refresh button?

Comment: Reloading the whole page, every time, isn't a little "heavy"? you could bring just the content that need to change using ajax... also I believe there are some servers that may restrict the reloading a little to avoid DoS attacks, making your game slow... Well is just a comment...

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the page with using the following function

```
var reload = function(){
  document.location = document.location;
}
```

So your HTML with the button may look like:

```
<button type="button" onclick="reload()">reload</button>
```

Comment: you need to reload the page - here's the code. I don't know where you need to put it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript method `reload`:

```
location.reload();
```

You need to use it on the click event callback.

I hope that helps :D

Comment: where do i put it? :O i tried this but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div#startgame").click(function(){
    $('body').trigger('load');
  });
});
```

You need to be sure you have one body tag. Or put an id for your desired body tag

Comment: where do i put it? :O it doesn't work inside the JQuery

Comment: @Runa. I edited the code. Put it at the end of file. Be sure you imported jQuery library

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  StartGame(); // You can start it from here too, removing the onload from body tag 
  
  // Intercept click event in your div, in this case by ID
  $('#StartGame').click(function(){
    StartGame(); // Call start game when it happens
  });
});
```

With a code like this you bind a call for `StartGame()` when you click you StartGame div.

With this you don't need to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
$('#StartGame').click(function(){
   location.reload(); //reload the page every time you click
});